# How to test Paypal IPN notification

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to get this PayPal IPN script work but it seems that i don't get the response from paypal .
I don't know what's the problem, is in the form or in the script:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost/home/menu/index.php" />
    <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost/home/menu/index.php" />
    <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://localhost/home/menu/php/inni.php" />
```

and this is the script inni.php:

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
if (!$fp) {

} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // vérifier que payment_status a la valeur Completed
        if ( $payment_status == "Completed") {
                         if ( $email_account == $receiver_email) {
//insert in db
          }
        }
        else {
                // Statut de paiement: Echec
        }
        exit();
   }
    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // Transaction invalide
    }
}
fclose ($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending PayPal to localhost.

Change the links (notify_url) to a publicly accessible URL or IP address.

PayPal sends notifications from their server, so sending to localhost will not reach you as localhost in this case would be the PayPal server itself.

Comment: i'm using lampp , and also i use the same url i mean localhost/index.php when the payment is made and paypal redirect me to the index page when the payment is successfully made

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward PayPal IPN requests to your local computer for it to work.
There are several projects dealing with this, both free and commercial.

The free and open source variant being: https://github.com/antoniomika/sish

One commercial variant: https://ngrok.com/

Ngrok is somewhat faster to implement since you don't need to configure the server.

To forward http requests to localhost with Ngrok

```
./ngrok http -host-header=localhost 80
```

Then in your browser open

```
http://localhost:4040/inspect/http
```

Copy your ngrok url from the status page

```
https://d1c7361aebf0.ngrok.io
```

Assuming your IPN notification url is

```
https://www.example.com/api/paypal-ipn
```

Update it to and start testing instant payment notifications

```
https://d1c7361aebf0.ngrok.io/api/paypal-ipn
```

Note: Make sure you disable all domain name related redirects for it to work.