# Testing Paypal IPN locally

Tags: meteor, paypal, paypal-ipn

based on [Paypal tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/), this is the form they provide for testing the IPN:

```
<form target="_new" method="post" action="https://www.YourDomain.com/Path/YourIPNHandler.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="SomePayPalVar" value="SomeValue1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="SomeOtherPPVar" value="SomeValue2"/>

  <!-- code for other variables to be tested ... -->

  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I got my IPN listener code in `server/routing.js` and used iron router and specified the path to `/ipn`. here is the code for it

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('ipn', {
        path: '/ipn',
        where: 'server',
```

so my question now, what URL should i put in the form instead of "https://www.YourDomain.com/Path/YourIPNHandler.php" URL? Because am testing it in my local machine "localhost:3000"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test Paypal IPN listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034987/how-to-test-paypal-ipn-listener)

Comment: @Sindis have you read through my question? it is different, and am using the links in that question because am the one who asked that question, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem friend. The solution was very simple.
Paypal does not allow test in your local machine: Paypal says: We're sorry, URL with port number is not allowed for IPN.
You must have a server with your "www.YourDomain.com". In my case for development tests I downloaded a "tunnel" application called NGROK which gives to you a testing domain. You can get it from [here](https://ngrok.com/download). 
Then will be enought just open the ngrok console and write the command:

```
> ngrok http -host-header=localhost 3000
```

After that execute your web application. After you've started ngrok, just open http://localhost:4040 in a web browser to review your domain provided by ngrok.
When you go to localhost:4040 in your browser ngrok show to you a http and http domains like they show in the examples.

```
http://92832de0.ngrok.io 
https://92832de0.ngrok.io
```

Now just replace "www.YourDomain.com" with this ngrok URL.

Hope this helps to you. Regards!

Comment: yes it helped, thanks. One question, the link i will use would be "http://92832de0.ngrok.io/ipn" or "http://92832de0.ngrok.io/routing.js"

Comment: Excellent, "92832de0.ngrok.io/ipn" will be your request URL.
Now you also can inspecting your traffic on the localhost:4040 and access from anywhere to "92832de0.ngrok.io/ipn"

Comment: @Ivan Rascon what is the command to use in Mac? when i user "./ngrok http" nothing happens

Comment: If you have already installed ngrok, use the command "help" to show the options, also check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188582/ngrok-command-not-found

Comment: @IvanRascon can you please check this question and help me if you came across the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043368/error-cannot-find-module-paypal-ipn

Comment: I have created a more detailed explanation on how to proceed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224196/how-to-test-paypal-ipn-notification/62297068#62297068