# Error: Cannot find module 'paypal-ipn'

Tags: meteor, paypal, paypal-ipn

Am using the forum in [Paypal tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/) to test the IPN listener, when i click on submit a new tab is opened and it says:

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'paypal-ipn' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) 
at Module.require (module.js:364:17) 
at require (module.js:380:17) at Object.Npm.require (/Users/mazinalmaskari/Desktop/code/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:150:18) 
at Object.Meteor.npmRequire (packages/npm-container/index.js:2:1) at [object Object].route.action (server/routing.js:6:30) at boundNext (packages/iron_middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1) at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
```

Am not sure where the problem is exactly, I get `500 Internal Server Error` in the ngrok when i click submit.

this is my IPN listener located in the server

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('ipn', {
        path: '/ipn',
        where: 'server',
        action: function() {
            var ipn = Meteor.npmRequire("paypal-ipn");
            var wrappedVerify = Async.wrap(ipn, "verify");

            var request = this.request;
            var verified;

            if (request.method !== 'POST') {

              this.next();

            } else {

              try {
                verified = wrappedVerify(request.body, {"allow_sandbox" : true});
              } catch (error) {
                //do something with error
              }

              if (verified === "VERIFIED") {
                var payment = request.body;
                //do something with payment
                Router.go('/upload');
              }

              this.next();
            }

        }
     });
  });
```

This is the form am using (from Paypal tutorial):

```
<form target="_new" method="post" action="https://ba13954b.ngrok.io/ipn">
          <input type="hidden" name="SomePayPalVar" value="SomeValue1"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="SomeOtherPPVar" value="SomeValue2"/>
 <input type="submit"/>
```

Any idea what might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Review the module as the error message indicate. But...
Try like this:

```
var ipn = Meteor.npmRequire('paypal-ipn');
```

Based on:
https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

Comment: okay will check it out. I already have that line in the IPN listener, it is in the question :) thanks